# Problems in Right join in SQl

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure also i have mention my expected output
please help me with query as i dont know much about sql query

Table Structure

**Table 1 : Emp Details**

```
    FName      Id  
    Pratik      1     
    Praveen     3     
    Nilesh      2
```

**Table 1 : JoinigDocument**

```
id    DocumentName
1     Leaving
2     Exp letter
3     birth cert
```

**Table 2 : EmployeeJoiningDocument**

```
EmpId  JoiningDocumentId
1        1
1        2
3        1
3        2
3        3
2        1
2        3
```

Expected Output :

```
FName      Id  JoiningDocumentId  DocumentName   
Pratik      1     1                  Leaving         
Pratik      1     2                  Exp letter      
Pratik      1     null               birth cert      
Praveen     3     1                  Leaving        
Praveen     3     2                  Exp letter      
Praveen     3     3                  birth cert    
Nilesh      2     1                  Leaving       
Nilesh      2     null               Exp letter      
Nilesh      2     3                  birth cert
```

Comment: Please include table names on the table structure.

Comment: What's the logic behind Flag column? How you came to know which row will have 1 and 0?

Comment: @Deepshikha flag(custom column jsut for representation) represent data is present in Employee table or not

Comment: @mxix added table names

Comment: @Nilesh You want all data from you Employee Table ?

Comment: @KhurramAli i want all data from Employee table and JoinigDocument indicating that document is present or not if present i will get id   if not ill should get null or empty value

Comment: @Nilesh You have 2 tables or 3 
you have mention JoinigDocument , EmployeeJoiningDocument, JoinigDocument as tables

Comment: @KhurramAli i have modified my question..by mistake i have mention only two tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a query as:

```
select  
       A.FName,
       A.Id,
       B.JoiningDocumentId,
       c.DocumentName
from @JoinigDocument C
cross join @EmployeeDetail A
Left join @EmployeeJoiningDocument B on B.EmployeeId = A.id and 
B.JoiningDocumentId = C.id
order by A.Id
```

First cross join `JoinigDocument` and `EmployeeDetail` table so that you get all possible combinations of  Employee and Documents irrespective of the fact that employee has that Joining Document or not. Then you need to do a left join to retain all these matches and find data corresponding to valid entries in `EmployeeJoiningDocument`.

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/XHGM25694)</kbd>

Comment: can you plz solve this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038975/replacing-id-with-actual-values-in-sql-server  i have spent almost 1 day solving this query